# Android color picker with TextInputLayout OutlinedBox style

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design, color-picker

in my Android app I use TextInputLayouts with TextInputEditTexts for user input and now I want to add a color picker that works like this picker from another app:

[image]

Is it possible to make it look like the other TextInputLayouts with the OutlinedBox style? I tried putting the color picker into a TextInputLayout but it seems to only accept EditTexts.

Answer (score 0):

Add background to your Layout instead of `TextInputLayout`, because `TextInputLayout` is used for `EditText` views.

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_stroke"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                <!--Your child views-->
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Color"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:paddingStart="3dp"
                android:paddingEnd="3dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```